# Storyboard with DoubleAnimation inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, storyboard, uwp

I have a `ListView` with a `ItemTemplate` in `XAML`, each item contains a `Button` and a `FontIcon`. I want to do a rotate animation on the `FontIcon` once the button is pressed. I already build the behavior outside of the `DataTemplate` where it's working fine, so I added the `Storyboard` to the `ListView` and now I'm getting an error that the `Storyboard.TargetName`. Is it possible to perform a `DoubleAnimation` on a specific element inside the `DataTemplate`, which is triggered by another element inside the `DataTemplate`?

I haven't done anything with animations in `XAML` before, so if I'm on the wrong track please let me know.

Here is the code of the `ListView` with the `Storyboard`

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemList">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="TestStoryboard">
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                        To="180"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="iconlist"
                        d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Button Click="ButtonTest_Click">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </Button>
            <FontIcon x:Name="iconlist" Glyph="###" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

For better understanding here is a screenshot of what I'm building. I want to rotate the emoticon with a click on the button inside the according item of the `ListView`:

[image: ListView]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `TestStoryBoard` is local to the data template; it is not a field on your class.

Second, you need to define a `RenderTransform` on the target so that the animation has something to animate. (That also simplifies greatly the specification of target property, as you can name the transform itself.)

Here's a slightly modified example, just so I could hack something together and claim it works -- it does, but isn't pretty:

```
<ListView
    Grid.Row="2"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="TestStoryboard">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Duration="0:0:0.2"
                            To="180"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="transform" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <Button Click="ButtonTestClick" Content="{Binding}" />
                <TextBlock Text="Hi">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform
                            x:Name="transform"
                            CenterX="50"
                            CenterY="20"
                        />
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The code-behind:

```
public string[] Items { get; } =
    {
        "One", "Two", "Three",
    };

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void ButtonTestClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UIElement clickedElement = sender as UIElement;
    StackPanel stackPanel = FindParent<StackPanel>(clickedElement);

    object value = null;
    stackPanel?.Resources.TryGetValue("TestStoryboard", out value);
    Storyboard storyboard = value as Storyboard;
    storyboard?.Begin();
}

public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject element)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    while (element != null)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
        T candidate = parent as T;
        if (candidate != null)
        {
            return candidate;
        }

        element = parent;
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Note that we need to pull the storyboard out of the `StackPanel`'s `Resource` dictionary.

I hope this can serve as a starting point for you.

Comment: Thank you, going through the VisualTree and finding the control to animate was the key to success!

Comment: If you scroll the list and use this it can cause some artifacts. But I am still not aware of the better solution - either no animation or this.